# Trying to fill a 2d array of structures in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, caching, dynamic, structure

As above, I'm trying to create and then fill an array of structures with some starting data to then write to/read from.
I'm still writing the cache simulator as per my previous question:
[Any way to get rid of the null character at the end of an istream get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264757/a)

Here's how I'm making the array:

```
struct cacheline
{
string data;
string tag;
bool valid;
bool dirty;
};

cacheline **AllocateDynamicArray( int nRows, int nCols)
{
cacheline **dynamicArray;

dynamicArray = new cacheline*[nRows];
for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ )
    dynamicArray[i] = new cacheline [nCols];

return dynamicArray;
}
```

I'm calling this from main:

```
cacheline **cache = AllocateDynamicArray(nooflines,noofways);
```

It seems to create the array ok, but when I try to fill it I get memory errors, here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
int fillcache(cacheline **cache, int cachesize, int cachelinelength, int ways)
{
for (int j = 0; j < ways; j++)
{
for (int i = 0; i < cachesize/(cachelinelength*4); i++)
{
    cache[i][ways].data = "EMPTY";
    cache[i][ways].tag = "";
    cache[i][ways].valid = 0;
    cache[i][ways].dirty = 0;

}
}
return(1);
}
```

Calling it with:

```
fillcache(cache, cachesize, cachelinelength, noofways);
```

Now, this is the first time I've really tried to use dynamic arrays, so it's entirely possible I'm doing that completely wrong, let alone when trying to make it 2d, any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Also, is there an easier way to do write to/read from the array? At the moment (I think) I'm having to pass lots of variables to and from functions, including the array (or a pointer to the array?) each time which doesn't seem efficient? 
Something else I'm unsure of, when I pass the array (pointer?) and edit the array, when I go back out of the function, will the array still be edited?

Thanks

Edit:
Just noticed a monumentally stupid error, it should ofcourse be:

```
cache[i][j].data = "EMPTY";
```

Comment: Use `vector` be happy.

Comment: I haven't chosen to use vectors for a couple of reasons: I've never used them before so wasn't sure about them, and the nature of the program (where you choose the size of the cache you want) wouldn't suit vectors (in my opinion)

Comment: Shouldn't `cache[i][ways]` be `cache[i][j]`?

Comment: Yeah I eventually realised that :P See my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You should find your happiness. You just need the time to check it out (:

[The way to happiness](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Comment: Deadline is tomorrow though, so not sure I have the time to learn something completely now :/